# screen switch does not happen on button click in kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am new to kivy. I want to switch to another screen (Signup screen) when 'signup' button is clicked on the main screen (Login screen). here is the python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') 
import ConfigParser
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Window.size = (700, 550)

class LoginPage(Screen):
    def switch_screen(*args):
       global sm
       print "i am in login and will switch to signup"
       sm.current = 'signup'

class SignUp(Screen):
    print "signup screen"
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginPage(name="login"))
sm.add_widget(SignUp(name="signup"))

class Test(App):
    icon = "C:\Users\shru\Desktop\download.jpg"
    title = "Member Login"
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
   Test().run()
```

Here is the .kv code

```
<LoginPage>:
      canvas:
         Rectangle:
            source: "C:\Users\shru\Desktop\m.jpg"
            size: self.size

      Widget:
         Button:
            size: 90,35
            pos: 380,200
            font_size:15
            background_color: (1,1,1,0.3)
            text: "SignUp"
            on_press: root.switch_screen()

<SignUp>:
     canvas:
         Rectangle:
           source: "C:\Users\shru\Desktop\m.jpg"
           size: self.size
     Widget:
         Button:
           size: 90,35
           pos: 380,200
           font_size:15
           background_color: (1,1,1,0.3)
           text: "hello"
```

This on execution returns blank screen. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create instances of your widget before the App is run, which is also before the kv file has been loaded, so your kv rules aren't applied and you see nothing.

Move the `sm =` etc. into the build method to fix this, the kv file is loaded before this method is run.

Answer (score 1):

These changes in the code made it work:

```
sm = ScreenManager()

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
       sm.add_widget(LoginPage(name="login"))
       sm.add_widget(SignUp(name="signup"))
       return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
      Test().run()
```